# How to use a class as a generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class

```
public class Customer
{
    ...
}
```

I also have a method that uses generics:

```
public static T Show<T>(DependencyObject sender, MessageBoxIcon icon, string caption, ObservableCollection<T> dataSource, MessageBoxButton button) where T : IComparable<T>, new()
{
    ...
}
```

Now, when I want to call this in my program:

```
Customer customerSelect = NoruBox.Show<Customer>(this, MessageBoxIcon.Box, "GridBox test", customerData, Noru.Controls.MessageBoxButton.SelectCancel);
```

I do get an error tho. It said that the type `Customer` can't be used as a type parameter `T` in `Show<T>(...)`. There is no implicit reference conversion from `Customer` to `System.IComparable<Customer>`.

---

I tried to do `public class Customer : IComparable` and add the following to the `Class`:

```
public int CompareTo(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as Customer;
    if (other == null) return 0;
    return CompareTo(other);
}
```

but this made no difference.

Comment: Your `Customer` class needs to implement `IComparable<Customer>`, not `IComparable`.

Comment: you need this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does your `Customer` class have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: Tnx for the link and my class had a parameterless constructor, that was also an earlier problem I had but was fixed before this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What aspect of each `Customer` instance do you want to compare? In the example below, I'm assuming that `A` holds the key value.

```
public class Customer : IComparable<Customer>
{
    public int CompareTo(Customer other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        return this.A.CompareTo(other.A);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constraint is requiring `IComparable<Customer>`, not `IComparable`:

```
public class Customer : IComparable<Customer> {

  public int CompareTo(Customer other) {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.